# Not able to add/append object on one to many field i.e. ICollection<obj>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```
//Contact class model
public class Contact
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public required IdentityUser User { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ChatRoom> ChatRooms { get; set; }
    }

// ChatRoom class model
public class ChatRoom
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Message> MessageObjs { get; set; } = new List<Message>();
    }
```

This is my controller, Here I am not able to add `chat_room` object to `other_user` and `loged_in_user` contact. There is only the `other_user` whose values is getting saved in Database.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRoom(int contact_id, string email, string room_name)
        {

            Contact loged_in_user = _context.Contact.Where(c => c.Id == contact_id).Include(c => c.ChatRooms).First();
            Contact other_user = _context.Contact.Where(c =>c.User.Email == email).Include(c => c.ChatRooms).First();

            ChatRoom chat_room = new ChatRoom()
            {
                Name = room_name,
            };
            

            _context.ChatRoom.Add(chat_room);
            
            other_user.ChatRooms.Add(chat_room);
            loged_in_user.ChatRooms.Add(chat_room);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            
            return View("Index");
        }
```

Comment: What is the question? What should happen? What actually happens?

Comment: Did you mean neither of the object has been inserted? Does any exception or error has been thrown? Have you checked the logs?

Comment: There is no exception or error thrown. The one which queried from email got save into the database and other one with contact_id never got save in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is my controller, Here I am not able to add chat_room object to
> other_user and loged_in_user contact. There is only the other_user
> whose values is getting saved in Database.

Actually, its only considering last statements which is `loged_in_user.ChatRooms.Add(chat_room);` so , based on your query and object creation, if you look at the logger, it will only execute one insert statement into the sql database as you can see below:

[image]

Its because, when you are querying `Contact loged_in_user`  it will find one entity and `Contact other_user` would find another entity, and if you look into the query tracker, it will only assign the `ChatRoom chat_room` object only once, because, entity framework doesn't allowing single one object into two different entities. Consequently, only your last statement considering insertion.

[image]

If you would like to update both enities together, you need to create `ChatRoom chat_room` twice. I have simulated, couple of test and you can try this way.

```
        int contact_id = 1;
        string email = "TestUser2.com";
        string room_name = "my chat room";

        Contact loged_in_user = _context.Contacts.Where(c => c.Id == contact_id).Include(c => c.ChatRooms).First();
        Contact other_user = _context.Contacts.Where(c => c.User.Email == email).Include(c => c.ChatRooms).First();

        

      

         var chatroom2 = new ChatRoom { Name = room_name };

        loged_in_user.ChatRooms.Add(chatroom2);

        var chatroom3 = new ChatRoom { Name = room_name };
        other_user.ChatRooms.Add(chatroom3);
      
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

If you look into the logger, you see, above modification creating two insert statement in database, by sql switch case statement.

[image]

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note:** If you need more details, you can r[efer to this official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-many)